# Weird failure in code when trying to add random array data to List<Bitmap>

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a slot machine in c# but there is a vague issue that confuses me.

I am trying to add some random data from a `Bitmap[]` into a `List<Bitmap>`:

```
public void Gamble()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            int r = (int)(new Random().NextDouble() * (fruits.Length - 1));

            GambledFruits.Add(fruits[r]);
        }
    }
```

For some reason the `List<Bitmap>` adds the first `int r` 3 times.

But when i add a `MessageBox` like this:

```
public void Gamble()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            int r = (int)(new Random().NextDouble() * (fruits.Length - 1));

            MessageBox.Show(r.ToString());

            GambledFruits.Add(fruits[r]);
        }
    }
```

It shows me 3 different random numbers and it adds the 3 different number instead of 3 equal numbers.

Comment: Use same ```Random``` object instead of new object instantiation on each iteration.

Comment: You're using `Random` incorrectly - you should only construct it once, because it uses the current time as a seed value (I think, to the nearest milisecond) so it will repeat values.

Comment: Is this is the complete code. ? where is List<Bitmap> used.

Comment: Thanks a lot @UladzimirPalekh and this worked :)

Comment: And @Dai ofcourse

Comment: This question has been asked literally thousands of times on this site, I am sure.

Comment: @Eric Lippert Sorry for that. I found it hard to search up a similar question like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use same `Random` object for all iterations. Also you don't need to use `double` values:

```
public void Gamble()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        int r = rnd.Next(fruits.Length);

        GambledFruits.Add(fruits[r]);
    }
}
```

But if you want to have really random values, you need to use cryptographic functions instead of `Random` class. But please note that these values can have not Gauss distribution.

Comment: For purposes of gambling, the bigger problem than lack of Gauss distribution is that `Random` is predictable.  And yes, people (e.g., Murat Bliev) have exploited this flaw on real slot machines.

Answer (score 3):

Random shouldn't be used like that - you should use the same instance three times:

```
public void Gamble()
    {
        var rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            int r = (int)(rnd.NextDouble() * (fruits.Length - 1));

            MessageBox.Show(r.ToString());

            GambledFruits.Add(fruits[r]);
        }
    }
```

This is the problem with `Random` - it doesn't really generate random numbers (it's just pseudo-random). But if you use the same instance it's much more random than with a new instance three times in a row.

And by the way, you don't have to use the double random number - you could simply use this:

```
var r = rnd.Next(fruits.Length);
```

As I believe that the messageBox was only there for debugging you could even use something like that:

```
GambleFruits.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(new Random(), 3).Select(r => fruits[r.Next(fruits.Count)]));
```

instead of the for loop. While it's arguable wether this solution is more efficient or more readable, I think it's a more *elegant* way to solve this.

For more information about c# random numbers generation, take a look at this: https://www.dotnetperls.com/random.

I hope I could help you.

Comment: Thanks alot for the explanation! :D

Comment: I was thinking of something similar `GambledFruits.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(new Random(), 3).Select(r => fruits[r.Next(fruits.Length)]));` because `Repeat` will use the same `Random` instance

Comment: @Slai, code from @MetaColon is working as ```0``` in ```Repeat()``` is not used at all. Your solution is good too as it don't need additional local variable for the ```Random``` instance.